# VB.NET WinForms implementing an interface

Tags: vb.net, winforms, interface

VB.NET

I want some WinForms to implement an interface, and be able to pass these to a procedure which can 'see' the implemented properties as well as the 'standard methods' of a Form. This is what I have so far...

```
Public Interface IMyInterface

    Property MyProperty As String

End Interface

Public Class MyForm

    Implements IMyInterface

    Private _MyProperty As String

    Public Property MyProperty() As String Implements IMyInterface.MyProperty
    Get
        Return _MyProperty
    End Get
    Set(ByVal value As String)
        _MyProperty = value
    End Set

End Property

End Class
```

then, elsewhere I have my method as follows...

```
Public Sub DoSomething(MyForm As IMyInterface)

    MyForm.MyProperty = "x"
    MyForm.ShowDialog()

End Sub
```

The obvious problem is that the compiler doesn't know what .ShowDialog is, and if I pass my form in as 'MyForm As Form' it doesn't know what 'MyProperty' is. I understand the reasons for this, but not how to solve this problem. Is a simple casting to Form the correct way to address this?

Many thanks.

Comment: You could of course add a ShowDialog or Display method to the interface.  Or even a GetForm method.  But what is going to be next?  The usual point of showing a dialog is to obtain the data that the user entered after you show it.  So you ought to declare a POCO that stores that data and a Boolean GetData(Poco data) method starts to make sense.  Now it is a complete implementation detail how that data is obtained, you'd use ShowDialog in normal usage and a mock in a unit test.

Answer (score 0):

You need to inherit `System.Windows.Forms.Form` to gain all regular form functionality and then Implement `IMyInterface`.

```
Public Class MyForm
    Inherits System.Windows.Forms.Form
    Implements IMyInterface
```

Passing `MyForm As IMyInterface` into the `DoSomething()` method is fine, however to use the regular form methods you'll need to cast it.  Alternatively you could pass in the `Form` and then cast to `IMyInterface`, your choice.

```
Public Sub DoSomething(MyIForm As IMyInterface)
        MyIForm.MyProperty = "x"

        Dim MyForm As Form = TryCast(MyIForm, Form)
        MyForm.ShowDialog()
```

Answer (score 0):

Another aproach can be using your own base class

```
Public Class MyBaseForm
    Inherits System.Windows.Forms.Form

    Public Property MyProperty As String

End Class
```

Then all your forms can inherit that base form

```
Public Class MyForm
    Inherits MyBaseForm

End Class
```

And you can use property and standard method of `System.Windows.Forms.Form` without casting

```
Public Sub DoSomething(someform As MyForm)
    someform.MyProperty = "Some value"
    someform.ShowDialog()
End Sub
```